# LiveSDK for iOS message to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, onedrive, live-sdk

I recently added OneDrive integration to my project and it works fine except for when I try to release the objects that use the SDK files.

I have tracked the cause down to calls on deallocated instances.

In the dealloc calls for **LiveConnectClientCore** and **LiveAuthRefreshRequest**, **cancel** methods are called on objects that have been deallocated.

All this stems from a pointer I have to a **LiveConnectClient**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LiveConnectClient *liveClient;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, I think it is the issue because of creating multiple instances of LiveConnectClient class. Creating shared Instance or global instance might solve this problem.

Comment: Yes this is what I did to get around it. I created a singleton class that holds onto the pointer to a single LiveConnectClient, this way it is never released.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ShareKit? It has no problems with OneDrive

Comment: No this is not via ShareKit, I use the LiveSDK (5.6.1) directly. I am not sure if the issue was fixed in a later version. I'll update this if I ever get back to this project.